# How to find which FBA users are in FBA roles

Tags: forms-authentication

We are using **FBA** accounts to grant external access to non staff in SP2010 Enterprise.

I need to find a way of discovering the memberships of the **FBA** roles so I can audit who has access to our sites.

I'm currently looking at running an SQL query against the FBA database but thought there may be another way.

Comment: Running a SQL query will probably be the quickest way to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack](https://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/). Hope it may help.

**Project Description** reads

> A forms based authentication pack for SharePoint 2010. It includes web
>   parts for registering users, changing passwords and password recovery.
>   It includes tools for managing users and roles and for approving
>   registrations.

Comment: Already use this and although it is a nice solution it does not allow you to see the users within the role - it only provides a quantity of users. Thanks though

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Source code is there. Give a try to modify it and then share it with us.

Comment: In the FBA pack code there is a method: Utils.BaseRoleProvider().GetUsersInRole

Comment: You have added a very useful information I guess. @Prakash-CrowCanyon thanks

Comment: I'm not a developer though so I have had to create a query which I'll post as an answer for anyone who is interested. Thanks @Prakash-CrowCanyon

Answer (score 1):

Running this query does the trick however I am sure there are superior solutions out there:

```
SELECT ROLE.RoleName, USERS.UserName, MEMBER.Email
FROM aspnet_Users AS USERS
INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles AS USERSINROLE
ON USERS.UserId = USERSINROLE.UserId
INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles AS ROLE
ON UsersInRole.RoleId = Role.RoleId
INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership AS MEMBER
ON USERS.UserId = MEMBER.UserId
ORDER BY ROLE.RoleName
```